# In .net MVC Is there a better way to hide dt elements than adding display: none to each?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

One of my views contains a `dl` element with a lot of the following structures repeated inside:

```
<dt>
    <label>Accept this thing?</label>
</dt>
<dd>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ThisThingAccepted)
</dd>
```

There are many such "things". I want the checkbox and label to disappear once the user has accepted the thing and posted the data back so it can be saved.

However, use of `div` and `span` elements inside a `dl` are disallowed, so the only HTML-legal way of doing this appears to be:

```
<dt  @if (Model.ThisThingAccepted) { <text> style="display: none;" </text> }>
    <label>Accept this thing?</label>
</dt>
<dd @if (Model.ThisThingAccepted) { <text> style="display: none;" </text> }>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ThisThingAccepted)
</dd>
```

Which is messy as all hell.

I know I could tidy it up a bit by using a custom display template, but is there a neater way to hide these elements?

Comment: Why are you using `<dt>` and `<dl>` elements (they are not appropriate elements for form controls)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I inherited this from a previous developer.

Comment: Suggest you read [The Description Term element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dt) - you might want to reconsider the use of those elements

Comment: Is there any reason why you just want to "hide" them instead of just not generate them? Do you need to re-enable them on client side? Else I'd simply do `@if (!Model.ThisThingAccepted) { <dt>
    <label>Accept this thing?</label>
</dt>
<dd>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ThisThingAccepted)
</dd> }`

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this , by adding a property in your model

```
public class YourModel
{
public bool ThisThingAccepted{get;set;}
public string CssClass{get;set;}
}
```

Creating a css class in your style sheet

```
.HideElements
{
 display:none;
}
```

When you are binding your model populate the css property
like

```
Public ActionResult GetDetails()
{
var data  = getdatafromsomewhere();

var model = new YourModel();
model.ThisThingAccepted = data.ThisThingAccepted;
model.CssClass = data.ThisThingAccepted ? "HideElement" : string.Empty;

return View(model);
}
```

On a side note you can use some other html elements here in place of dt,dl.
When you are rendering your view use the css class from model and assign it to elements where you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I presume they need to be present in the UI on render?  If not, wrap them in an if statement and don't render them at all.

I sometimes do:

```
style='@(Model.ThisThingAccepted ? "display: none;" : "" }'
```

Or use a method in a function block of the view:

```
@functions {
   public string GetInitialState(ModelType model)
   {
       return model.ThisThingAccepted ? "style=display:none;" : "";
   }
}

<dt @GetInitialState(Model)>
```